# WPF Text not updating in Task

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application using Caliburn.Micro and I'm trying to populate a field. I want it to try 5 times and wait 2 seconds between each try. I can't figure out why my WPF application isn't updating. It seems to update the first time it runs through the `While` loop but that's it.

I just know that I'm making a huge mistake somewhere. Can someone please explain where I'm going wrong?

```
public ShellViewModel()
{
    Computername = EnvironmentHelpers.ComputerName;

    RunProcessAsync();
}

private async Task RunProcessAsync()
{
    await FullNameAsync();
}

private async Task FullNameAsync()
{
    string fullname = ADHelpers.GetFullADName();

    while (fullname != "Failed" && _attemptsToCollectFullName < 5)
    {
        _attemptsToCollectFullName++;

        Fullname = $"Retrying... {_attemptsToCollectFullName}";

        await Task.Delay(2000);

        fullname = ADHelpers.GetFullADName();
    }

    if (fullname.Contains("Retrying..."))
    {
        Fullname = "N/A";
    }
}
```

#### Update

`Fullname` binds to the view using the magic of Caliburn.Micro:

```
private string _fullname;

public string Fullname
{
    get { return _fullname; }
    set
    {
        _fullname = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Fullname);
    }
}
```

My ShellView XAML looks like this:

```
<TextBlock x:name="Fullname" />
```

Comment: `RunProcessAsync()` is not being awaited.

Comment: How can I await it though? It's running in the constructor

Comment: Maybe through a static factory method.

Comment: Constructors are for constructing.  Don't start tasks, timers, etc from constructors.  Create a method that is called from your application engine under the normal control of your software.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I definitely need to do some research on this as I've never heard of it. Do you know of a good resource or examples?

Comment: Check out @Stephen Cleary blog [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/), more precisely [this](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much @Decoder94 ! Looks like another deep dive for tomorrow morning <3

Comment: WPF has an event that it triggers when the view is loaded. Use it to run your code.

Comment: @SILENT Do you mean in the `ShellView.xaml.cs`? Does this work with MVVM?

Comment: @I.TDelinquent: Even if `FullNameAsync()` is called from the constructor and not being not awaited, it's still being executed. So this is not your main issue. How is `Fullname` implemented and how do you bind to it in the view?

Comment: @mm8 I have updated my question with my binding method using Caliburn.Micro

Comment: @I.TDelinquent: And where do you expected to see the value in the view?

Comment: @mm8 I have updated again with my XAML section :-D

Comment: @I.TDelinquent: Your code should work, i.e. you should see "Retrying...x" in the view, provided that you have set up everything correctly. Did you confirm that the property gets set as expected?

Comment: @mm8 Yep everything was working fine. I think the async wasn't set up properly, which meant that the UI was being blocked someway or another. I have since completely changed my approach with the help of previous commenters and everything appears to be working as I would like :-)